# Grails minimum value fetch

Tags: grails, grails-orm, createcriteria

I am working to fetch the minimum value from a table in Grails where the vehicleid and the type is given

there are many values associated from that vehicleid and type i need to fetch the minimum date associated with that vehicleid . I have tried this but it is not working for the startDate param.

```
List vehicleDate= Table.createCriteria().list() {
   and{
      eq('vehicleid',vehicleIDGiven)
      eq('type',type)
      min("startDate")
   }
}
```

what could be the query like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to fetch the minimum value, you could use a projection as documented [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

Not tested, but your criteria should look something like this:

```
def result = Table.createCriteria().list() {
    and{
        eq('vehicleid',vehicleIDGiven)
        eq('type',type)
    }
    projections {
        min("startDate")
   }
}

println "Minimum start date is ${result[0]}"
```